# Can we add something to the FAQ?

Tags: feature-request

I feel like the last 10 question reviews I've done have been someone solely wanting to remove a "thanks!" from a new user's question. This is a "too minor" edit, and honestly as a reader I don't care if the poster has been kind enough to thank us for our time.

I'm not seeing anywhere in the FAQ a list of guidelines about *how* to edit someone else's post. Can we add some suggestions? Preferably which include something to the effect of "If all you're doing is taking out a 'thank you' or making a title into title case where it was sentence case, it's too minor"?

Comment: I think it's a great idea, these 'thank you' edits are becoming a usual thing lately (it's specially frustrating when there are actually more important things to edit in the same question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree. Just removing a "thanks" is really an unnecessary edit.

Comment: So how do we edit/add to the FAQ?

Comment: Post a meta question, make sure the community agrees, and a moderator can make a change.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Did the first, got the second, you have a moderator diamond, nu?

Comment: One vote is hardly a consensus. But I'll keep an eye on this post. Also, now that I think about it, it might not be possible to edit all parts of the FAQ... Hmmm. Will look when I get home.

Answer (score 3):

There's actually no real info on 'how to' edit, so to add the 'thank you' rule we should agree on some guidelines.

Only the first part of the faq is editable, the rest is boilerplate. So it has to be in the top section, or not at all, at least for now. Our best option (I think) is to create a **new question in Meta and link to it** when small changes are made.

I created this one, please feel free to edit for improvements!:

> [When should I edit posts?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/526/when-should-i-edit-posts)

It's based on the [SO edit faq section](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit).

Comment: Outstanding! Thank you!

Comment: Only the first part of the faq is editable, apparently the rest is boilerplate. I'll ask around to see if it can be changed or not :s