# Should I reject minor 'hairsplitting' edits?

Tags: discussion, editing

Past few weeks, I have approved some very minor edits -- just spelling corrections or comparably insignificant edits. Should I reject these, even though they are factually correct? It seems to me we don't want to waste everyone's time on minor things like these.

Related: [Can we add something to the FAQ?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/523/can-we-add-something-to-the-faq)

Comment: Spelling and grammar corrections are acceptable - anything that improves a question is a good thing. related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118238/is-it-an-accepted-behavior-to-suggest-correct-grammar-or-spelling-in-the-edits - or you can click edit and uncheck the marked as helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually approve them given that the intent of the edit is to improve the quality of the post and that they've made a reasonable effort to correct all the issues with the post. I don't see it as a waste of my time, we're a relatively small community and suggested edits are sparse.

In cases where there's another spelling mistake or two that I see, I usually "improve" the edit. I don't expect someone to be perfect and catch every little minor spelling or grammar error, so I'll give the benefit of the doubt.

When there's a negligible edit on a post that clearly has lot's of other issues is when I'll actually reject it as too minor.

My rationale behind this is "*I do it, why shouldn't they be allowed?*". I'm sure you could go through my edit history and find bunches of 1-5 character edits to posts correcting spelling or grammar. Sometimes there just isn't anything else to improve upon, but that doesn't mean we should allow the errors to remain in place.

Comment: Spot on! Only reason I sometimes prefer **not** to edit something minor is if I don't believe it's a good idea to bump it to the top of the list in the Home.

Answer (score 2):

I generally approve them, albeit a little begrudgingly, because I want the little box on my own exchange to go away.